# Calculando taxas no R

Tags: banco-de-dados, r, data.frame, matemática

Possuo o seguinte dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame(Individuo=c("1","2","3","4","5","6"), 
  Sexo=c(2,4,4,2,4,2),Ocupaçao=c(1,1,2,2,1,2),
  Raça=c("Branco","Negro","Pardo","Branco","Pardo","Branco"), 
  Estudo=c(10,12,14,16,13,11))
```

Onde, em Sexo os indivíduos do sexo masculino estão representados pelo número 2 e os do feminino pelo número 4, em Ocupaçao o número 1 representa os indivíduos ocupados e 2 representa os desocupados.

Como faço para calcular a seguinte relação,(Desocupados)/(Ocupados+Desocupados)? 
(Essa é a fórmula para a taxa de desemprego)

Além disso, há alguma maneira de se representar graficamente(Dispersão,linhas ou barras) tal relação por diferentes grupos? Por exemplo, (Desocupados)/(Ocupados+Desocupados) somente para homens brancos ou qualquer outra combinação nesse sentido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que o seguinte faz o que quer, exceto os gráficos.
Em primeiro lugar, transformei as colunas `Sexo` e `Ocupaçao` em fatores e atribuí-lhes `labels` descritivas, `Masculino/Feminino` e `Ocupados/Desocupados`.

```
data$Sexo <- factor(data$Sexo, levels = c(2, 4), labels = c("Masculino", "Feminino"))
data$Ocupaçao <- factor(data$Ocupaçao, levels = 1:2, labels <- c("Ocupado", "Desocupado"))
```

Agora, é só usar as funções `table` e `prop.table` para obter a relação `Desocupados/(Ocupados+Desocupados)`.

```
tbl_ocup <- table(data$Ocupaçao)
prop.table(tbl_ocup)
#    Ocupado  Desocupado 
#        0.5         0.5
```

Para obter relações por outros critérios mais complexos, tais como a taxa de ocupaçao por raça, fazemos em três operações, `aggregate`, `tapply` e a divisão destes últimos resultados por `table`.

```
agg <- aggregate(Ocupaçao ~ Raça, data, length)
TaxaOcup <- tapply(data$Ocupaçao, data$Raça, FUN = function(x) sum(x == "Desocupado"))
TaxaOcup <- TaxaOcup/table(data$Raça)
tbl_ocup_raca <- cbind(agg, TaxaOcup)
row.names(tbl_ocup_raca ) <- NULL
tbl_ocup_raca <- tbl_ocup_raca[c(1, 2, 4)]
names(tbl_ocup_raca)[3] <- "TaxaOcup"
tbl_ocup_raca
#    Raça Ocupaçao  TaxaOcup
#1 Branco        3 0.6666667
#2  Negro        1 0.0000000
#3  Pardo        2 0.5000000
```